# Trouble with https:// access to various sites

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer, https, microsoft-edge

I'm experiencing a rather odd problem right now.

My PC is running Windows 10 Enterprise, v1803, and about 10 days ago, suddenly several web sites stopped working properly. I first experienced it trying to watch a TV show on Amazon Prime, in Google Chrome - the video couldn't be played anymore (and I didn't find anything on Google's or Amazon's web sites support areas). I was still able to watch that show in Firefox - so I really didn't care much about that glitch.

But then, I started noticing that certain sites that I tend to visit with IE/Edge don't work anymore, either - mostly the Swiss national TV site (which has sports videos of the past week etc. - this one never works in Firefox, unfortunately). Suddenly, neither IE/Edge nor Google Chrome were able to connect to that site using https:// - Chrome mentions something like:

> This site can’t provide a secure connection
>   www.srf.ch sent an invalid response.
>   ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

while IE/Edge let me know :

> Can’t connect securely to this page. This might be because the site uses outdated or unsafe TLS security settings.

I haven't knowingly changed anything on my system - nothing that has to do with networks, firewalls or anything like that - but of course with Windows 10's automagic background updates, I cannot be sure what might have gone in without me knowing about it.

Any ideas? Is there anything I can check or tweak to make these sites work again? I *can* connect to them just fine from a Windows 7 VM / laptop, but that's just a bit annoying if that would be the only way to get back that access....

Comment: Can you be more specific about the type of error message that is appearing in Chrome? You should be able to see something like `example.com uses an unsupported protocol. ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH`.

Comment: @MichaelFrank: Updated my Chrome error message

Comment: Do you have the proper date/time on your system?

Comment: @pbies: yes, definitely

Answer (score 2):

Reasons behind ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR in Chrome:

1. Invalid system time
2. Firewall blocking the website or IP address
3. Website could be blacklisted in the `c:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` file
4. Chrome extension blocking the website
5. Cookies or cache not cleared for a long time

Check for the above and try to resolve the problem. If the above does not work - the site you are accessing may have expired certificate.

Comment: Thanks for your hints - I verified and checked everything, disabled all extensions - but nothing helped :-( I still get the "cannot provide a secure connection" :...

Comment: Have you checked the websites on another computer/smartphone?

Answer (score 0):

There are many reasons why this could happen, in my case it was because the computer itself was too old. It was running windows XP and Chrome didn't support the certificate that we were using because it was too old.

Maybe this can help: https://www.multimediaxp.com/post/52/solved-this-site-cant-provide-a-secure-connection-uses-an-unsupported-protocol-err-ssl-version-or-cipher-mismatch